# rename the categories and add the missing categories to a Series PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to rename the categories and add the missing categories to a Series.

My code:

```
codedCol = bdAu['Bordersite']
print 'pre:'
print codedCol.head(10)
codedCol = codedCol.astype('category')
codedCol = codedCol.cat.set_categories(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'])
print 'post:'
print codedCol.head(10)
```

When I do this I get NaN as the result.

```
pre:
0    3
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    5
7    3
8    3
9    3
Name: Bordersite, dtype: int64
post:
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
dtype: category
Categories (10, object): [a, b, c, d, ..., g, h, i, j]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks
Kheeran

Comment: What's your ideal result?

Comment: I've added an answer...let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First or creating `catagories` you can use `.astype('category')`, but `categories` are added from your column or `Categorical` with parameter `categories` where are defined.

You can use:

```
codedCol = bdAu['Bordersite']
codedCol = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(codedCol, categories=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
print (codedCol)
0    3
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    5
7    3
8    3
9    3
dtype: category
Categories (10, int64): [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And then [`rename_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.rename_categories.html), but number of items in categories have to be same, else error:

> ValueError: new categories need to have the same number of items than the old categories!

```
codedCol = codedCol.cat.rename_categories(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'])
print (codedCol)
0    d
1    d
2    c
3    c
4    d
5    e
6    f
7    d
8    d
9    d
dtype: category
Categories (10, object): [a, b, c, d, ..., g, h, i, j]
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael.  That is what I was looking for.

Jossie, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You've set the categories to the following: `['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']`. The current values in the column in `codedCat` do not match any of the categories. Therefore, they get re-set to `NaN`. For further reading, consider this example [from the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
In [10]: raw_cat = pd.Categorical(["a","b","c","a"], categories=["b","c","d"],
   ....:                          ordered=False)
   ....: 
In [11]: s = pd.Series(raw_cat)

In [12]: s
Out[12]: 
0    NaN
1      b
2      c
3    NaN
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [b, c, d]
```

Since `"a"` is not a category, it gets re-set to `NaN`.

Comment: @jezrael edit your code so I can remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`add_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html#pandas.Series.cat.add_categories) to add_categories to a series.